# Sass: How to divide padding equally to all horizontal nav items if we add or remove any navigation items?

Tags: sass

I'm using Sass and want to make this type of navigation flexible so if client want to add or remove any items from the menu. then all menu items should adjust/fill-up in the available space.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this using Sass math and variables?

Comment: You do see that the SCSS code in your jsFiddle is improperly indented, which makes it harder to read the code? **Properly indented demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nTcRv/12/

Comment: I *believe* you can achieve this if you set them to `display: table` but I'm not familiar with correctly setting up display:table so I'm only going to be able to give you this starting point.  Hopefully someone else has more knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with Sass as you need to know the number of li items there are on your .nav list. You can do it with javascript as you obviously know. Here's how I did it -> http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/nTcRv/15/

Comment: I will know number of li items. So please tell me how to do it with Sass

Comment: It's not possible to do a good job with SASS alone. If you want no js, then you're best bet, which is perhaps even the simplest, is to use display: table as nzifnab suggested. Take a look -> http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/nTcRv/17/